# Why it did not retrieve posted data in asp.net mvc controller with jquery.post()

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc, vb.net

I'm using an ASP.NET MVC web app written in VB.NET. I try to send data with jQuery to my controller.

Here is my controller code

```
<HttpPost()>
    Function GetData(p As DataManager) As JsonResult
        'Dim user As New User
        'user.user_name = puser.user_name
        'user.isadmin = puser.is_admin
        Dim x As New List(Of DataManager)
        x.Add(p)
        Return Json(p, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)
    End Function
```

then here is my data model for class DataManager

```
Public Class DataManager
    Public user_name As String
    Public is_admin As Boolean
End Class
```

Here is my jQuery code for sending data

```
$("#btn-valid").click(function () {
        var user = {
            user_name: 'test',
            is_admin: true
        }
        $.post("http://localhost:57069/Home/GetData/", user, function (data)
        {
            alert("data sent !!"+ data.user_name);
        },'json');
```

here is my request in developer mode in my browser
[image: my request details]
[image: My response details]
please

The request from jQuery it succeed but the problem is on the response i get null values assigned to my json object

please help !

Comment: `$.post("http://localhost:57069/Home/GetData/", user).done(function(data) { console.log(data.user_name) });`

Comment: it return null too

Comment: what does `console.log(data)` return?

Comment: have a debugger point before alert and check what do you get in data variable

Comment: console.log(data) return null value, data value is null befiore alert

Comment: can you please verify that your JsonResult is returning correct value i.e not null values

Comment: how can i verify it ? i will try debug

Comment: run and have a debugger at your jsonResult method in controller

Comment: i debugged method, parameter "p" of datamanager is { user_name: nothing , is_admin: False} and method return same object

Comment: my data sent from jquery did not retrieve in server-side(controler) this is my main problem, any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a little test, I believe that your problem is related to member definition of this model class:

```
Public Class DataManager
    Public user_name As String
    Public is_admin As Boolean
End Class
```

Both variables are declared as fields, and unlike `Boolean` field, the `String` field might not be recognized by action method when string value passed from JSON request. I tried to set all members in `DataManager` class as properties with `Property` keyword:

```
Public Class DataManager
    Public Property user_name As String
    Public Property is_admin As Boolean
End Class
```

And then the `data` response contains this object during console inspection, indicates that the string property is assigned properly:

```
data: {user_name: "test", is_admin: true}
```

Therefore, I concluded that you need string properties instead of fields inside model class to pass string values.

Working example: [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/JzA5fY)

Comment: it work thank so much ! it works and  u won the post